# How to call a WP Class inside my theme

Tags: php, settings-api, namespace, autoloading

I wrote a WP theme using namespaces and autoload. Everything went smooth until I started to use WP classes which I understand of course because I understand how namespacing works.
My question is, is there a way possible to use a Wordpress class inside one of my theme classes, for example I want to use `$wp_customize`, an instance of `WP_Customize_Manager`? How would I achieve that, keeping my OOP theme structure.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Pat J. I was able to solve it. It works perfectly and this is how it looks like:

```
class ColorController extends BaseController
{
    public function register()
    {
        add_action('customize_register', array($this, 'theme_customize_register'));
    }

    public function theme_customize_register($wp_customize)
    {
        // Text color
        $wp_customize->add_setting('text_color', array(
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'refresh',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'text_color', array(
            'section' => 'colors',
            'label' => esc_html__('Text color', 'theme'),
        )));

        // Link color
        $wp_customize->add_setting('link_color', array(
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'refresh',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
            'section' => 'colors',
            'label' => esc_html__('Link color', 'theme'),
        )));

        // Accent color
        $wp_customize->add_setting('accent_color', array(
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'refresh',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'accent_color', array(
            'section' => 'colors',
            'label' => esc_html__('Accent color', 'theme'),
        )));

        // Border color
        $wp_customize->add_setting('border_color', array(
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'refresh',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'border_color', array(
            'section' => 'colors',
            'label' => esc_html__('Border color', 'theme'),
        )));

        // Sidebar background
        $wp_customize->add_setting('sidebar_background', array(
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'refresh',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new \WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'sidebar_background', array(
            'section' => 'colors',
            'label' => esc_html__('Sidebar Background', 'theme'),
        )));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$wp_customize = new \WP_Customize_Manager();
```

...since, as I understand it, WordPress core puts all its classes, functions, etc. in the global namespace.

**Edit**

It appears that `$wp_customize` may be a bad example, as it's a global variable (so, in your theme, all you should need to do is declare `global $wp_customize;` before you use it).

If you're looking to learn about how to use the Customize API, I'd recommend you read through [the official Customize API documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/). Note that, anywhere you need to call a WordPress class or function, you can do so by prepending a `\` to its name.

Comment: Where do I declare `global $wp_customize`? I tried declaring it in functions.php before I initialize my namespaced theme but I got an error. I will follow up with this thread later today and if you need me I'll post some code and/or my theme structure.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the Customize API docs. You should be able to do anything in the theme's `functions.php` file, since that file is treated as, essentially, a plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've already solved it. Check my update.

Comment: If my answer helped you out, please feel free to mark it Accepted, so that others with a similar question might find help.